# How do I 'magrittr' pipe to the summarize() function of the R package 'Hmisc'?

Tags: r

I am trying to reduce the nested parenthesis using pipes of package `magrittr`. So I am trying to implement `summarize()` function of `Hmisc` package.

```
 data(iris)
summarize(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,mean)
```

How to use pipes `(%>%)` of `magrittr` package in R?

Comment: Is there any reason to use `Hmisc::summarize` over `dplyr::summarize`? `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% dplyr::summarize(mean(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: No specific reason. I was  trying some packages in R.I did simple commands through pipes but was not able to do summarize.

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can use `with` like this :

```
library("Hmisc")
library("magrittr")
data(iris)
iris %>% with(summarize(X = Sepal.Length, by = Species, FUN = mean))
```

EDIT :
Even better you can use `%$%` operator and skip the `with` step :

```
iris %$% summarize(X = Sepal.Length, by = Species, FUN = mean)

##     Species Sepal.Length
##1     setosa        5.006
##2 versicolor        5.936
##3  virginica        6.588
```

Comment: Thanks.Can we break summarize function itself using pipes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dplyr` package.

```
> library("dplyr")
> iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(length = mean(Sepal.Length))
```